# What determines the amount of coins I get from burning objects?

Tags: little-inferno

I'm wondering what determines how many coins I get for burning an object. It seems like the bigger the object the more I get, but I'd like to know specifics.

What determines the amount of coins I get from burning objects?

Answer (score 2):

The amount of coins you get from burning objects is directly proportional to its cost. The more it cost (and the longer it took to get delivered), the more coins you'll get from burning it.

There may be some variation such as glass not giving as much coin as a wooden doll, for example, but in general you'll get more coin for burning more expensive stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Each burned item will return you the amount of coins you spent on it plus a variable range of extra coins that depends on the item being burnt.

The [Little Inferno Wiki](https://little-inferno.fandom.com/wiki/Catalogs) lists profit ranges for items in the first 3 catalogs that line up with [my own personal testing](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12Iz4eunTCeAWFmvH-FAPiRhnk8N_A4s3Ie6_a07uYp0/edit?usp=sharing).

#### [Catalog 1](https://little-inferno.fandom.com/wiki/Chimney_Stuffer)

- Items 1-5 earn 1¢
- Items 6-15 earn 1-2¢
- Items 16-17 earn 1-3¢
- Items 18-19 earn 2-4¢
- Item 20 earns 2-6¢

#### [Catalog 2](https://little-inferno.fandom.com/wiki/Totally_Recalled_Toys)

- Items 1-10 earn 1-2¢
- Items 11-15 earn 1-3¢
- Items 16-17 earn 1-4¢
- Items 18-19 earn 2-5¢
- Item 20 earns 2-6¢

#### [Catalog 3](https://little-inferno.fandom.com/wiki/Snooty_Foodie)

- Items 1-5 earn 1-2¢
- Items 6-10 earn 1-3¢
- Items 11-15 earn 2-4¢
- Items 16-17 earn 2-5¢
- Items 18-19 earn 1-7¢
- Item 20 earns 2-11¢

As for items that can't be purchased, personal testing gave me the following results

- Letters always earned 2¢
- The terms and conditions earned 16¢
- The delete button earned 16¢
- Bugs earned 2¢ on a fresh file, but 23¢ on a file with Catalog 7 unlocked